# Show Current Messages While Loading New Message

Tags: android, listview

I have an in-app messaging system. Currently, the process is not ideal. Every time you click send, it reloads the whole activity, resulting in a temporary blank screen and loading dialog. Apps like facebook messenger seem to instantly show the new message when I press send. How is this possible?

Here are my current steps.

**1.** The activity loads all messages from the database between two users.

**2.** When you type a message and click 'send', it executes an insert query and adds the message to the database.

**3.** After the message has been inserted, it reloads the activity and new messages are shown.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best in terms of memory but I'd bet its quicker than reloading the activity from the db.

Create an activity-wide array of db object's (where db objects store all the info from the database)

When the app launches, load up the array with everything from the db so far. Then when a new comment comes in or is add the new comment to the db and copy the array to include the new comment.

Then display everything from the array rather than straight from the database.